# Install RethinkDb on ubuntu Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rethinkdb

I install RethinkDb on Ubuntu Google Cloud Platform.
I also change firewall rule to open port 8080

[image: Firewall-config]

But when I open http://server_ip_addres:8080 on web browser.
This site can’t be reached
 server_ip_addres refused to connect.

What is wrong with my ubuntu virtual machine?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using tags, did you checked the target tag has been added to the instance?

Also please check if there is any UFW(Uncomplicated Firewall) or Iptables rule has been enabled if they are active add the port 8080 or turn off the internal firewalls.